# Django forms initial value user_full_name

Tags: python, django, forms

Is the any solution to get django's user_full_name as a initial value for form? My idea was to display a django's form on the end of shopping to finish a order. I want also do put into a form total value, but this is for later.
I did something like this:

```
        user_dane = request.user.get_full_name
        koszyk = request.session.get('koszyk', [])
        produkty = list(Produkt.objects.filter(pk__in=koszyk))
        suma_cen = Produkt.objects.filter(pk__in=koszyk).aggregate(suma=Sum('cena'))
        suma_wszystkich_cen = suma_cen['suma']
form=ZamowienieForm(initial={'imie_nazwisko':user_dane, 'kwota_do_zaplaty':suma_wszystkich_cen})
```

but this is working only when request.method is POST.

```
if request.method =='POST':
        form = ZamowienieForm()
```

According to documentation I shouldn't initial a empty form with POST... Is there any chance to have a user full name into a form?

Here is the form class:

```
class ZamowienieForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Zamowienie
        fields = ('imie_nazwisko', 'kwota_do_zaplaty', 'miejscowosc',
                  'ulica','numer_domu', 'numer_mi‌​eszkania', 'kod_pocztowy',)

    class NewMeta:
        readonly = ('imie_nazwisko','kwota_do_zaplaty',)
```

Comment: What the definetion of your form class?

Comment: `class ZamowienieForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Zamowienie
        fields = ('imie_nazwisko','kwota_do_zaplaty','miejscowosc','ulica','numer_domu','numer_mieszkania','kod_pocztowy')

    class NewMeta:
        readonly = ('imie_nazwisko','kwota_do_zaplaty')`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you only need to initialize your form once, and not inside a conditional check if the request is a `GET` or `POST`:

```
def your_view(request):

    form = ZamowienieForm(
        request.POST or None,
        initial={'imie_nazwisko': request.user.get_full_name(),
                 'kwota_do_zaplaty': suma_wszystkich_cen}
    )

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        # do whatever
```

This way you are always passing in the initial value, and if `request.method == 'GET'`, then `None` is passed as the first positional argument to the form.

Also, [user.get_full_name](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L339) is an instance method, not a property, so using `request.user.get_full_name` only returns the bound method, not the actual value. You have have to call the function using `()`

Finally, this will only work for users that are authenticated. The [anonymous user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymous-users) object in Django won't return any user-specific information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this inside `ZamowienieForm` class

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ZamowienieForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['imie_nazwisko'] = self.initial.get('imie_nazwisko')
    self.fields['kwota_do_zaplaty'] = self.initial.get('kwota_do_zaplaty')
```

Although I don't understand why "initial" is not working out of the box

Comment: Looks like in this case `request.user.get_full_name()` can not be a initial value or I don't know how to use this.Initial value can be a string here for example and is displayed fine.